# Empty form in filelist CE after upgrade to TYPO3 6.2.27

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Hej.
I have a 6.2.27 and since the last update the editor can't edit filelists anymore. Permissions are set and have been working for the last years. 
The content element is opened, I can see the tabs, but no fields.

[image: Screenshot]

Only error I can get is on dev console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Clickmenu is not defined

Any ideas? Cache is deleted, T3 source is overwritten with a fresh one. 
Admin can edit without any errors.

The error message is identical to https://forge.typo3.org/issues/24170

Comment: What was the version you upgraded from? TYPO3 CMS 6.2.26 or an older version?

Comment: Yes, it was 6.2.26 to .27.

Comment: The problem is definitely located in the JS compression in the backend.
When I enable [BE][Debug] it is working again for editors.
CompressionLevel is set to 0.